# Esri maps with React and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, esri

I have a simple react application created with:

```
npx create-react-app myapp --template typescript"
```

I want to include an interactive map component.

Following the instructions at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/typescript-setup/ :

1. I added the dependencies:

```
    npm install --save arcgis-js-api
    npm install --save @types/arcgis-js-api
```

2. I added the following tags in the head tag of public/index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.19/esri/themes/light/main.css">
    <script>
      var locationPath = location.pathname.replace(/\/[^/]+$/, "");
      window.dojoConfig = {
        packages: [
          {
            name: "app",
            location: locationPath + "/app"
          }
        ]
      };
    </script>
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.19"></script>
```

3. I created my component (Map2D) like this:

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import EsriMap from "esri/Map";
import MapView from "esri/views/MapView";

const Map2D = () => {

  const theView = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  if(theView && theView.current)
  {
    const map = new EsriMap({
      basemap: "streets-vector"
    });

    const view = new MapView({
      map: map,
      container: theView.current,
      center: [-118.244, 34.052],
      zoom: 12
    });
  }

  return (
    <div ref={theView} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', margin: '0', padding: '0' }}>      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map2D;
```

4. I updated App.ts to return a view with my component:

```
import './css/App.css';

import Map2D from './Components/Map2D';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Map2D />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

After that, running

```
yarn start
```

I get

```
Failed to compile.

./src/Components/Map2D.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'esri/Map' in '/workspaces/myapp/src/Components'
```

How should this code be changed, in order to compile and run?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please attach a screenshot of your webpack config? I think you are missing this in your **resolve** portion of your **webpack** config:

```
alias: {
    "esri": path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/arcgis-js-api/')
}
```

Check here please https://github.com/Esri/jsapi-resources/blob/master/4.x/webpack/demo/webpack.config.js

Comment: The application generated with `npx create-react-app`  didn't contain a webpack.config.js at all. I added it with the content you shew in module.exports, resolve, then I added "webpack.config.js" among the "include"s of tsconfig.json file. Unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: Other failing attempt: add "node_modules/arcgis-js-api/index.d.ts" among the "include"s of tsconfig.json file
Other failing attempt: add `/// <reference types="arcgis-js-api" />`  at the beginning of the component